# Java 8: Which is the better way to fetch an object based on attributes in a collection

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Considering the following class:

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "text")
@ToString
public class Foo {
    private Long xKey;
    private Long yKey;
    private String text
}
```

If i have `List<Foo> fooList` and in this i have to fetch list elements where :

`{xKey, yKey} combination is in Map<Long,Long> combination = {{10L,20L},{11L,35L},{4L,1L}}`

1 st way is by for each iteration and using .get() method:

```
for(Entry<Long,Long> entry: combination.entrySet()){
    Foo tempFoo = new Foo(entry.getKey(),entry.getValue(),null);
    Foo actualFoo = fooList.get(tempFoo);
    System.out.println(actualFoo);
}
```

2 nd way is by java 8 streams

```
combination.foreach((k,v) -> {
    Foo actualFoo = fooList.stream()
           .filter(f -> f.getXKey.equals(k) && f.getYKey.equals(v))
           .findFirst()
           .orElse(null);
    System.out.println(actualFoo);
})
```

Which one is better in performance and coding practice ?

EDIT: After looking into comments realised that there is a mistake in first code snippet instead of `fooList.get(tempFoo);` it should have been `fooList.get(fooList.indexOf(tempFoo));`

Comment: A `List<Foo>` doesn’t have a `get(Foo)` method.

Comment: added edit comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, a `List<Foo>` doesn’t have a `get(Foo)` so apparently, this is only a description for something like `list.get(list.indexOf(foo))` to get the actual instance for your template, implying a linear search like with your Stream variant.

In that regard, *both* a discouraged, as they imply a linear iteration over a `Map`, performing another nested linear search on the list, whereas a `Map` typically has a lookup operation better than a linear search.

So you should iterate over the list and perform a lookup on the `Map` instead:

```
for(Foo foo: fooList) {
    if(foo.getYKey().equals(combination.get(foo.getXKey()))) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
}
```

the only difference being that the elements don’t appear in the `Map`’s order, in case the map *has* a defined order (`HashMap` hasn’t) and that it won’t print `null`s for mappings not having a corresponding `Foo` in the list.

Of course, you can also write it as `forEach` operation:

```
fooList.forEach(foo -> {
    if(foo.getYKey().equals(combination.get(foo.getXKey()))) {
        System.out.println(foo);
    }
});
```

or Stream operation

```
fooList.stream()
       .filter(foo -> foo.getYKey().equals(combination.get(foo.getXKey())))
       .forEach(System.out::println);
```

which are all equivalent.

What you should *not* do, is replace an intrinsic Collection API lookup operation like `Map.get` with a Stream search operation.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, i have add edit comment regarding the mistake in first code snippet

Comment: Extending this question, If the combination contains all three fields {xKey,yKey,text} and these are present in list of object similar to foo .
What would be the best way to look up for them

Answer (score 3):

You can have it much shorter:

```
fooList.stream()
  .filter(f -> Objects.equals(f.getYKey(), combination.get(f.getXKey())))
  .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: I should have reloaded the page before writing an answer. However, I keep my answer as it emphasizes the other differences between the OP’s variants and this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You treat the list as a set, so I would suggest changing the implementation accordingly. Having it as a set, you will have far better performance, example when using `HashSet` as the implementation. In that case I would also strongly advising against trying to stream the new set implementation, as a simple lookup will bi a faster working like an index.

Comment: I wanted to preserve order so LinkedHashSet i guess

Comment: You might also look into `TreeSet` as it enforces the sorting while adding elements. Not better, just different.

Answer (score 0):

The second solution is much more readable. The first one will not work because the expected parameter for get in list is an int which is an index to the list. For loop and aggregate operations have essentially the same complexity, so there is no real performance difference, except maybe the first solution is slightly worse because it is creating those temporary Foo objects.